Am I supposed to slow down my development speed when I am too good for my team?
First a little bit of a background. I have aways been a pretty decent developer with 5 digit reputation on stackoverflow in my real profile :D On top of that I was a successful olympic competitor in mathematics in my school/student years. Unfortunately, I ended up in the nordics which loves equality. Now to my problem:
I was a tech lead to a 6 person team and during this period I have produced more lines of code than the whole team together :D Even though I was tech lead I aways see myself as a developer. Now at one point we got a team lead and on top of that I started noticing people complaining more and more from different things around me so I kind of decided to step down as a tech lead plus there was too much hierarchy with one tech lead and one team lead for 6-7 person team. So I stepped back.
Now here comes the beautiful thing. After I stepped down i had more time to focus on development and in 2 weeks now I have 2 times more code than the whole team together has produced. Now I think it is a matter of time until the others start complaining about it.
The key thing here is that this is not the first time I am in a similar situation :D
What is the correct thing to do. Should I code the way I am used to code this way producing more than everyone else together. Or am I supposed to artificially adapt myself to the team tempo in order for us to deliver as a team. Now the thing is that if we deliver as a team it will take twice the amount of time compared to if I just do my magic. So what is the correct strategy to handle this disproportion ?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This looks like a good point in time to reflect on your skills.
Someone bragging only about their LOC and putting out a disproportionate volume of code is a liability, not an asset.
Now, this might of course all be just because you did not think to mention all the code quality and maintenance and documentation and … work that you do anyway. Though not considering those worth mentioning would also be alarming…
If you want to be that lone wolf developer then a good strategy would be to look for a job that does not involve having to ignore half a dozen people. If you want to be a better developer or even an actual lead then a good strategy is to stop and listen to the complaints people have about your work.
You might find out just how fast a team with an actual lead can deliver. :D

see my comment about lines of code under the other post.

@Pesho I have seen it and it does not change the message in any positive way. There shouldn’t be so much boilerplate and configuration that you can produce more LOC with it than anyone writing meaningful code together. That is a total maintenance nightmare and should be automated or managed in some other way than a single person doing that for weeks! By doing so anyway such baggage is enshrined and takes ages to reliably replace with a proper solution.


Should I code the way I am used to code this way producing more than everyone else together ?

Yes. You should go at the speed that you feel comfortable with.
Continue to write high quality code (with very few bugs). Don't overwork.
At the same time, it is important to spend time helping your teammates with technical issues if they ask for your help. This way you can build a better work relationship with your coworkers and the new team lead. This will help you a lot in the future.

Usually, one needs both the hard skills (technical coding skills) and the soft skills (people skills) to be successful and to move up the ladder in the workplace.


I have produced more lines of code than the whole team together

"Lines of code" is infamously not something to brag about.
The usual way of evening out genuine differences in capability, is to allocate better developers to more difficult or subtle challenges, and to companies with better paid jobs.
I don't see any reason to artificially slow down your own work. If you're getting tasks done well ahead of the allocated time and there's no question about the quality, then simply use the time as you see fit.

Well it matters. Because lines of ccode can be tedious configuration or deployment job. Hundreds of lines boilerplate code that everyone else is just to lazy to write. So yes when I see someone generating a lot of lines of code and at the same time producing decent quality, It matters very much. Especialy for integration type of project where half of it is either mapping type of code or configuration or deployment in between tens of integrations.
We are talking about new development project, not a maintanancec one. Someone is supposed to write the code at the end of the day.

If you're writing hundreds of lines of boilerplate code, and you have spare capacity, you should be looking at ways to automate that/abstract it away.

@Pesho, but an intelligent developer - an informed one - would know the laughable history of measuring developer output by "lines of code", and the ambiguity of such a measure. You wouldn't measure an author primarily by the length of their book.

@Steve i agree with you but we Are not talking about that kind Of developer but a seniour developer I am measuring the effort done every day. And the effort has a reflection on the Lines Of code - added and deleted. Yes I agree that it is not an optimal meadurment, but when we talk about a project that is new development and you see a significant difference it is a marker that something is stinking.

@matfreake Tell me you need to write a configuration for SFTP that will go from one network to another. You dont Get it from the first attempt so you make 2-3 deployes via github action triggered on a commit f.ex. Squasing is discoraged in our team. How do you automate this ?

Nothing wrong with that. But effort does not correspond to productivity; number of lines of code written is still nearly irrelevant. Otherwise, the guy who writes horrible code and debugs his way to success would be a better programmer than you are, since he's writing more lines. Ditto the one who does not factor code out into shared (ideally reusable) routines, etc etc etc. If your company has a vague clue, nobody is counting lines of code; at most they are counting function points or some similar metric of the estimated work needed to complete the task and its importance. Forget LOC.

If you are really a senior developer, you should have learned this long ago.

@Pesho: "lines of ccode can be tedious configuration or deployment job. Hundreds of lines boilerplate code that everyone else is just to lazy to write." - I am genuinely not sure whether these examples are supposed to show "many lines of code are good" or "many lines of code are bad".

@Pesho A lot of my most productive (and satisfying) days involve me producing negative LOC. LOC is an absolutely worthless measure for value produced.

@PlayerOne I am counting both added and deleted Lines when measuring developer activity. Of course. I am not just counting added.

@Pesho, any style of counting lines is an inappropriate way to assess the work of a software developer. People are talking about "deleted lines" not as something you should also count, but to try and demonstrate the absurdity of your approach - which in your great naivety you are not realising. Any alteration that a developer applies to a codebase is highly variable when the alteration is analysed narrowly as a mechanical act. Part of the competence of a developer consists of devising appropriate alterations and avoiding inappropriate alterations. (1/3)

The vast majority of the working time of a developer is spent on perceptual and cognitive activity inside the mind of the developer. Doing this internal work badly or not at all, is still consistent with being able to do outward work to alter the codebase, but the frequency with which the alterations are appropriate falls, and fixing inappropriate alterations tends to beget more alterations (which may again be inappropriate). All this bad work registers mechanically in the same way as good work. (2/3)

The reason good and bad alterations to the codebase register the same on a mechanical analysis of LOCs added or changed, is because the distinguishing factor is the appropriateness of the alteration, and deciding what alterations are appropriate to make to the codebase, is an expert professional task which has to be done in context and which is done by the developer. (3/3)
